# what is the difference between memory allocated by VirtualAlloc and the memory allocated by std::vector

Tags: c++, memory-management, portable-executable

i tried to understand it but all what i understood so far is that using VirtualAlloc can allocate large memory pages for large buffers for example and std::vector too but VirtualAlloc i can commit the page i can set the permission to read,write , or execute and i can't do that with std::vector or can i? am basically trying to allocate memory for building a pe file that i read from my (disk). i also want to use std::vector since its much more modern way of allocating memory since its done automatically by using RAII.

Comment: this is not about what is more modern. `std::vector` is a standard container of objects, VirtualAlloc as a function that merely allocates memory from the windows api

Comment: @idclev463035818 so am guessing using std::vector.resize() is not like VirtualAlloc? because i saw some sources that uses std::vector and some uses VirtualAlloc and both of them are the same and am wondering how is that possible?

Comment: You aren't comparing apples to apples here, an `std::vector` is a container, intended to store arbitrary objects in contiguous chunk of memory, which it happens to allocate using whatever means necessary. VirtualAlloc is a low level memory allocation function provided by OS. A given stl implementation may actually use it, or any other similar ways to allocate the std::vector memory, but you really shouldn't be comparing the 2.

Comment: @BorisLipschitz thanks i guess then using VirtualAlloc is better since i can control which memory type i want , access rights, size etc....

Comment: @zeroaceee Nooooo. You should be using the standard language interface to the memory system. You only dig down into the OS memory handling system if you have a specific need for that type of accesses. Unless you have a specific need please don't do it. The language interface to memory handling allows for re-use of space very efficiently without any work being done by you as the programmer. You would use the OS layer memory management if you were doing things like creating your own memory management system of for interacting directly with the OS.

Comment: One advantage of `std::vector` is that it allows small memory allocations, whereas `VirtualAlloc` works with memory pages, which are normally at least 4096 bytes. Therefore, `VirtualAlloc` only allows large allocations. However, in your case, you will have to use `VirtualAlloc` if you want the code you read from the PE file to be executable. The memory allocated by `std::vector` and other standard library functions is always read/write, but never executable.

Comment: @MartinYork thank you for the advice and yes i need to use it

Comment: @AndreasWenzel this is the best answer so far thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

std::vector is a container that manages an array on the back end and provides functions that help you interact with it easily, with the bonus of being able to increase and decrease it's size.  This is implemented as part of the C++ Standard Library.

VirtualAlloc() is a Windows API function and only works on Windows.  It allocates page(s) of memory and returns the address of the allocated memory.

Using std::vector as intended, you don't know the address of the array and should avoid interacting with it directly.

If you need an array that can expand or shrink in size use an std::vector

If you need to create a dynamic variable, use a pointer and keyword 'new'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    int* new_ints = new int[300];

    //do whatever

    delete[] new_ints;

    return 0;
}
```

If you're allocating memory on Windows and using the 'new' keyword doesn't fit your needs, consider using VirtualAlloc() as an alternative.  I have never required VirtualAlloc() but I have used VirtualAllocEx() because it allows you to allocate memory in an external process.

I would not consider std::vector and VirtualAlloc() as alternatives to each other, they both have their individual use cases.